# Arithmetic problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Prove that $(a^2:a^2+16)=1 \lor 4 \lor 16$

I know that $(a:b)=(a:b+ka)$ with $k\in\Bbb Z$

So:

$(a^2:a^2+16)=(a^2:a^2+16-a^2)=(a^2:16)=1\lor4\lor16$

This is enough to prove this?

Comment: what does $\lor$ mean?

Comment: Do you know basic modular arithmetic? In particular, artihmetic modulo $\;4\;$ ?

Comment: @Shobhit The command comes from "Logic OR". As for the question, it's close. But you haven't yet ruled out $2$ or $8$. They're also possible answers to $(x:16)$, so why can't they be answers to $(a^2: 16)$?

Comment: $\lor$ means or

Comment: Is $\;(a:b)\;$ the same as the g.c.d. of $\;a\,,\,b\,$ ?

Comment: No, I don't know about arithmetic modulo

Comment: Yes,is g.c.d, exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to explain a little more why $(a^2:16)=1\lor4\lor16$.
For example why $(a^2:16)=2$ is impossible?
Hint: $2=2^1$.

Comment: Power with base 2?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

As $\sqrt{16}=\pm4,$

need to deal case by case  $a\equiv 0,\pm1,2\pmod 4 $